# Implementing U2-Gates on Cirq

Tags: cirq, universal-gates, qasm, qasm2circ

I am interested in using the QASM2Cirq methods to make this gate: u2(0, np.pi, q[0]).

How can I build that object using Cirq rather than QASM string value passed onto cirq.

Answer (score 3):

From the [spec](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.03429), $U_2(\phi, \lambda) = U ( \frac{\pi}{2}, \phi, \lambda)$. We can use Cirq's [QasmUGate](https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/blob/11b1433ea15676efd32e1e291dd5dd0618aee799/cirq/circuits/qasm_output.py#L30).

```
import cirq
from cirq.circuits.qasm_output import QasmUGate

q0 = cirq.NamedQubit('q[0]')
u2_gate = QasmUGate(0.5, 0, 1) # The angles are normalized to the range [0, 2) half_turns
circuit = cirq.Circuit(u2_gate(q0))
```